# Return Struct from a C++ function to Python in SWIG

Tags: c++, python-2.7, c++11, struct, swig

I have a C++ header which returns a struct having 3 elements. How can I make python accept the struct variable properly?

This is what I have in the C++ function :

```
  // Function name myfunc
 struct velocity
 {
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > u;
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > v;
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > w;
 }; 

 velocity velo;  //Creating object

 velo.u = sum(umean,pu);
 velo.v = sum(vmean,pv);
 velo.w = sum(wmean,pw);

 return(velo)
```

This is my Python implementation, after using SWIG

```
 import numpy
 from myfunc import *    # importing C++ myfunc library
 My = 100       # Matrix dimensions
 Mz = 100
 z = myfunc(My,Mz)    # Supplying the matrix dimensions to the myfunc library
 print(z)
```

The error message I get upon executing this:

```
 <myfunc.velocity; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'velocity *' at 0x2951ae0> >
```

I know that I have to somehow define in SWIG to make python take a struct "as is". 
Is there any way? Or any alternative method you may suggest? Here is my SWIG file

```
 %module myfunc
 %{
 #include "myfunc.h"  
 %}

 %include "std_vector.i"
 // Instantiate templates used by example
  namespace std {
  %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
  %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
  %template(twodvector) std::vector< std::vector<double> >; 
  }

 struct velocity
 {
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > u;
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > v;
 std::vector< std::vector<double> > w;
 };

 %include "myfunc.h"
```

Note that I have declared a struct here. This compiles successfully on SWIG but I do not know how to use it in Python to actually get the C++ struct!

Comment: Please also post your swig interface file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error message:

```
<myfunc.velocity; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'velocity *' at 0x2951ae0> >
```

It just indicates you have a SWIG proxy object that wraps a pointer to a velocity object.  You can just access `z.u[0][0]`, for example, to access an element of one of the double vectors.

**Edit**

Here's an example with typemaps defined for `vector<vector<double>>`.  They are not pretty, but allow assignment of Python "list of lists" to the `velocity` members directly:

```
%module x

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4701 4706 4996)
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%template(vector_double) std::vector<double>;
%template(vector_vector_double) std::vector<std::vector<double> >;

// Input typemap converts from Python object to C++ object.
// Note error checking not shown for brevity.
// $input is the Python object, $1 is the C++ result.
//
%typemap(in) std::vector<std::vector<double> >* (std::vector<std::vector<double> > tmp) %{
    for(Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < PySequence_Size($input); ++i)
    {
        auto t = PySequence_GetItem($input,i);
        std::vector<double> vd;
        for(Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < PySequence_Size(t); ++j) {
            auto d = PySequence_GetItem(t,j);
            vd.push_back(PyFloat_AsDouble(d));
            Py_DECREF(d);
        }
        Py_DECREF(t);
        tmp.push_back(vd);
    }
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// Output typemap converts from C++object to Python object.
// Note error checking not shown for brevity.
// $1 is the C++ object, $result is the Python result.
//
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<double> >* %{
    $result = PyList_New($1->size()); // Create outer Python list of correct size
    for(size_t i = 0; i < $1->size(); ++i)
    {
        auto t = PyList_New((*$1)[i].size()); // Create inner Python list of correct size for this element.
        for(size_t j = 0; j < (*$1)[i].size(); ++j) {
            PyList_SET_ITEM(t,j,PyFloat_FromDouble((*$1)[i][j]));
        }
        PyList_SET_ITEM($result,i,t);
    }
%}

%inline %{
    struct velocity
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > u;
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > v;
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > w;
    };

    // A test function with an in/out velocity parameter.
    void myfunc(velocity& vel)
    {
        for(auto& v : vel.u)
            std::transform(begin(v),end(v),begin(v),[](double d){return d*1.1;});
        for(auto& v : vel.v)
            std::transform(begin(v),end(v),begin(v),[](double d){return d*2.2;});
        for(auto& v : vel.w)
            std::transform(begin(v),end(v),begin(v),[](double d){return d*3.3;});
    }
%}
```

Use example:

```
>>> import x
>>> vel=x.velocity()
>>> vel.u = [1,2,3],[4.5,6,7]
>>> vel.v = [1,2],[3,4,5]
>>> vel.w = [1],[2,3]
>>> vel.u
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.5, 6.0, 7.0]]
>>> vel.v
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
>>> vel.w
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0]]
>>> x.myfunc(vel)
>>> vel.u
[[1.1, 2.2, 3.3000000000000003], [4.95, 6.6000000000000005, 7.700000000000001]]
>>> vel.v
[[2.2, 4.4], [6.6000000000000005, 8.8, 11.0]]
>>> vel.w
[[3.3], [6.6, 9.899999999999999]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I can access elements that way. However, I still need to be able to access each 2D std vector u,v  or w as a complete array in Python, without having to iterate through elements. Is that possible?

Comment: You can access by row and get a tuple via `z.u[0]`; otherwise, you can write a `%typemap` to fully translate the `vector<vector<double>>` to a Python list of lists.  No time now, but I'll update with an example later if you like.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen. I can access the tuple now. It would be great to all of us if you could post an example. I am new to SWIG.

Answer (score 4):

Mark Tolonen is right, the behavior you're seeing is not an error. If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to print an instance of myfunc.velocity

AFAIK for any python object to be printable, it needs to have the __str__ method defined. Normaly that's built-in, but since you're wrapping a C-struct, you have to define one explicitly. I reckon there are different ways to do this.

**Extending the struct:**

You can use Swig's [*extend directive*](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_class_extension) to define the missing function in C/C++.

```
%extend {
   const char* velocity::__str__() {
      std::stringtream ss;
      ss<< "[ ";
      std::copy($self->u.begin(), $self->u.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(ss," "));
      ss << std::endl;
      std::copy($self->u.begin(), $self->u.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(ss," "));
      ss << std::endl;
      std::copy($self->u.begin(), $self->u.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(ss," "));
      ss << "]" << std::endl;

      return ss.str().c_str();
   }
}
```

This should add a function __str__ to the velocity struct that will subsequently integrated into the generated Python wrapper.

**Extending the generated Python code:**

Another approach would be to [define additional methods to the auto-generated Python-Wrapper](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn42). You can add Python code to the Swig interface file using the `%pythoncode%` directive. Depending on your language preferences, this might be easier to do:

```
%pythoncode %{
def __str__(self):
    # this is probably horribly inefficient
    return "[" + str(self.u) + "\n" + str(self.v) + "\n" + str(self.w) + " ]"
%}
```

Swig has an extensive documentation, have a look at the [Python chapter](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python) to learn more about tighter integration.

**Writing convenience wrapper**

Of course, you could also define a second Python wrapper class which inherits from myfunc.velocity and define all the missing features there.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort! I needed to save the data from C++ into a suitable python data type. However, when I need to print I guess your tips will come in handy.